# Where is ALL the css that defines boostrap img-responsive class and other classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I looked on the boostrap website, but nowhere can I find what css is behind the classes, for example:

```
"img-responsive"
```

I want to modify it in my styles.css file file for an override, but I don't know how to find the native css that applies to that class ;)

Comment: Use Ctrl+f to find. What you want to modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there in bootstrap.min.css itself. click this [link](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css) for find that css from cdn bootstrap

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking, had to unminify it though...is there a page where the file is in normal format?

Comment: If you download source code from bootstrap site [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)  then it will not minified version. It will be normal file .

Comment: The easiest way to modify bootstrap styles is to set your own style rules into an external style sheet with the selectors that you want to modify and simply call that style sheet AFTER you call the bootstrap style sheet. That way you get the existing css for BS and the modified CSS rules will override the BS one because they are called into the page after the BS style sheet.

Comment: There is also an [unminified version](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) on the CDN.

Comment: Thank Skelly, this is EXACTLY whay I was looking for ;)